# How do you download a text file from a server using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a .txt file that I want a user to download and I am currently using this:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename('file.txt');
                        header('Expires: 0');
                        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                        header('Pragma: public');
                        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
                        readfile('file.txt');
                        exit;
```

When I download the file using this, the contents of the file start of with all the HTML and PHP used prior to this part of the script e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
Actual file contents
```

How do I download the file so that only the actual content is there and not the code?

Comment: Complete the code, don't understand where your problem is .... Please don't give the whole code to any idea if you are using <?php to parse PHP, or where the download link should be

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your code and check file.txt is present.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename('file.txt'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
readfile('file.txt');
exit;
```

Comment: All the HTML and PHP is still there in the text file. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Check whether permission issue? because I have checked in my system that if I dont have that file in my system, that time I am getting file with php code.